# Create an object of different class in a third class in objective c and modify the details

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to IOS development. I have class which contains the foll. details:

```
@interface GeoFenceReferenceDetails : NSObject {
    NSString* directionType;
    NSString* fenceCode;
    NSNumber* fenceId;
    NSString* fenceName;
    NSString* geoFenceType;
}
```

Another class "Utility"  which is used to create dictionary:

```
-(NSDictionary *) createGeoReferenceDict2: (GeoFenceReferenceDetails *) geoFenceDetails {    
return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        geoFenceDetails.directionType, @"directionType",
        geoFenceDetails.fenceCode, @"fenceCode",
        geoFenceDetails.fenceId, @"fenceId",
        geoFenceDetails.fenceName, @"fenceName",
        geoFenceDetails.geoFenceType, @"geoFenceType",
        nil];
}
```

Now I want to create an object of GeoFenceReferenceDetails in a third class which gives output in the following manner:

```
{
directionType = None;
fenceCode = 12;
fenceId = 81;
fenceName = "ABC";
geoFenceType = Circle;
}
```

Here's what I am doing. I am creating a "fenceDetails" object of GeoFenceReferenceDetails in the third class and then doing this:

```
 fenceDetails = [[GeoFenceReferenceDetails alloc] init];

fenceDetails.fenceId=[NSNumber numberWithInt:121];
 NSLog(@"%i",[fenceDetails.fenceId intValue]);
  NSDictionary* geoFenceReference = [[Utility sharedInstance] createGeoReferenceDict2:fenceDetails];

NSLog(@"%@ ",[geoFenceReference description]);
```

But all I'm getting is

```
{

}
```

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your .h interface class declaration:

```
@interface GeoFenceReferenceDetails : NSObject {
    NSString* directionType;
    NSString* fenceCode;
    NSNumber* fenceId;
    NSString* fenceName;
    NSString* geoFenceType;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *directionType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fenceCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fenceId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fenceName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *geoFenceType;
```

and this to your .m implementation file

```
@synthesize directionType, fenceCode, fenceId, fenceName, geoFenceType;

- (void)dealloc {
    self.directionType = nil;
    self.fenceCode = nil;
    self.fenceId = nil;
    self.fenceName = nil;
    self.geoFenceType = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSString *)description {
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", self, self.directionType, self.fenceCode, self.fenceId, self.fenceName, self.geoFenceType];
}
```

Wrote this withouth IDE, so i appologise for typos, if any. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That means your dictionary object is not allocated or does not contain any value.

There are few things you need to check.

1. Check if `sharedInstance` allocates the `Utility` object.
2. Also make sure it the dictionary object `geoFenceReference` is not nil.
3. Put the breakpoint the debug the code.